# Setting up administrator rules in firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hi I'm trying to implement a database in which clients can send their complaints online and some supervisor would be able to review them, The database I used is firebase,

as the database owner I'm authorized to check the contents of the database but how do I let that supervisor check them without me being in the picture?

I heard it's called "Setting up a Dashboard" or something but when searching I couldn't find any thing android-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth
token {
   "rules": { 
     "users": {
        "$uid": { 
           ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".write":"$uid === auth.uid" }
     }
    } 
   }
```

For More Info Check out link below
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart